# Why does Jboss EAP 7 load previous and actual configuration and so on alternately?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, devops, wildfly-8, jboss-eap-7

I have an angular app into a war, deployed works fine. But sometimes it serves the correct files and sometimes not. Evaluating the app, I request for a file mifile.js, sometimes it returns the current file, but other times it gives me back the file of the previous version.
I've tried with Postman and I realize that.

I have made a configuration in JBoss which puts an http-header to the file and reboots the server. Sometimes the current correct file is served with the custom http header, and sometimes it returns the previous file and without the http header since on that occasion it had not done that configuration (http header).
Based on this I come to the conclusion that the Jboss loads the current configuration a few times, and other times the previous configuration.

Any have an idea how to resolve this?.

Comment: do you mean that it caches previous version of your js file? did you check for cache busting?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a browser cache issue - clear your browser cache & try for this. But if not then:
1. Check if only current\latest war file in present deployments directory i.e latest war is getting deployed
2. If you are running on local\dev environments, clear your "tmp" & "data" directory from your $JBOSS_HOME\standalone or $JBOSS_HOME\domain & start the server. Hopefully you should get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This means JBoss is fetching the previous version of js file from tmp/vfs folder,try deploying your war in exploded format by keeping the deplyment scanner attribute `auto-deploy-exploded` to true.